# Jquery horizontal drop down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I want to make a drop down menu. I try to do something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/GPpbz/11/

```
<div>
    <nav>Parent Menu</nav>
    <nav>Sub Menu</nav>
    <nav>Sub Menu</nav>
</div>
```

But I have a problem. When mouse leave from parent li, sub menu container slideUp. It should visible during mouse over on sub menu container. Maybe I cant explain, but if you look example, you understand me.

How can I solve this problem. Or Do you offer something different? (Sub menu is 100% width an inline)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much better if you change your html to this

```
<nav>
    <ul id="top_menu">
        <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">deneme</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
           </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">deneme</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

and write appropriate jquery for this.

Comment: In this time, there is another problem with positioning about sub ul list. It's position left is starting from parent li element. I want all sub ul list to same left starting position.